# Python adding data in multi-dimensional dictionary

Tags: python

```
while (E > 0):
    line = raw_input("enter edges : ")
    data = line.split()
    mygraph[data[0]] = {data[1] : data[2]} //this line 
    print mygraph
    E-=1
```

Desired data structure:

```
mygraph = { 
        'B': {'A': 5, 'D': 1, 'G': 2}
        'A': {'B': 5, 'D': 3, 'E': 12, 'F' :5}}
```

i want to add multiple entries for same key like
but mycode is taking only one value for one node and then replacing 
the   entries.How to do that?

Comment: if given input 1 2 3 and 1 3 6. i want to save both in dict mygraph .how to do that

Comment: please add sample input and output.

Comment: enter edges : 1 2 3         output is  :      {'1': {'2': '3'},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first add an empty dictionary for the key `data[0]` if it doesn't already exist, then add the values to it. Otherwise you just wipe out it out every time you loop.

The two usual ways are either to use [**`setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) on a normal dictionary:

```
mygraph.setdefault(data[0], {})[data[1]] = data[2]
```

or use [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) where the default is an empty dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> mygraph = defaultdict(dict)

>>> edges = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 6]]
>>> for edge in edges:
...     mygraph[edge[1]][edge[2]] = edge[3]

>>> mygraph
{1: {2: 3,
     3: 6}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
mygraph[data[0]] = {data[1] : data[2]}
```

with these:

```
if not data[0] in mygraph:
    mygraph[data[0]] = {}
mygraph[data[0]][data[1]] = data[2]
```